# Foreign key relationship with composite primary keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Which is the best way to create a relationship between two tables when referenced table has a composite primary key?

```
table1{
   id,
   name
}

table2{
   id1,
   id2,
   name
}PrimaryKey(id1, id2)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way is this

```
alter table t add constraint fk_t_id1_id2
foreign key (id1, id2) references table2(id1, id2);
```

As Gordon said, the best option is create an auto incremental ID and make this the primary key.

Comment: I'm struck that this is basically a copy of my answer, posted half an hour afterwards.

Comment: Yes sorry. I was need in of boost me. I aprove your answer soon. No worry

Answer (score 4):

The only way is using both keys:

```
alter table t add constraint fk_t_id1_id2
    foreign key (id1, id2) references table2(id1, id2);
```

However, I would encourage you to add an auto-incrementing column to `table2` so such relationships can use a single key.

Comment: I wish add an ID AI PK, but i cant alter that table. Thank you so much for your help. I need upvote's on my question to achive the next badge..wich is very hard.